# D3 polygonContains() for simple rect

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have used `polygonContains(polygon, [x,y])` in the past and I notice that the `polygon` parameter takes coordinates. I do not have that kind of data structure, I have more of a "pre-fab" SVG shape if you will. Specifically SVG rects.

**Question:** What are some options for implementing the `polygongContains()` call when you actually only have SVG rects?

My initial thought was to reverse engineer the SVG rect by doing this at rect creating:

```
.on('click', function(d) {
    var containing_rect = d3.select(this);
    console.log(containing_rect)
    console.log(containing_rect.x1)
    var points_contained = d3.selectAll('circle').filter(function(d) {
        return !d3.polygonContains(containing_rect, [x(d.x),y(d.y)]);
    })
})
```

But `containing_rect.x1` appeared as `undefined` in the log, which leads me to believe my reverse engineer approach will not be able to get the end points of the rect.

Perhaps there is a better way to interface with `polygonContains()` in terms of passing arguments to have an SVG rect be used as a 4 sided bounding polygon (that the call expects).

Comment: What is `x1`? have in mind that `containing_rect` is just a D3 selection. Anyway, you can do this by different approaches: you can convert the rect in a rectangle, or create your own function.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I was trying to retrieve the coordinates that comprise the SVG shape. I noticed `x1` works with other things like paths, but I found out it's not the way to go here.

Comment: Well, I have no idea of what you're talking about with `x1`. Anyway, I'm writing a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own function to check if the circle is inside a rectangle.

For instance, this function I just wrote:

```
function containing(container, point) {
    var border = container.node().getBBox();
    var coordinates = {
        left: border.x,
        right: border.x + border.width,
        top: border.y,
        bottom: border.y + border.height
    };
    if (point.attr("cx") > coordinates.left && 
        point.attr("cx") < coordinates.right && 
        point.attr("cy") > coordinates.top && 
        point.attr("cy") < coordinates.bottom) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

It takes two arguments, `container` (the rectangle) and `points` (the circles), both as D3 selections.

Here is a demo of the function, I'm creating 100 circles and positioning them randomly. Those that fall outside the rectangle are coloured yellow, those that fall inside are coloured blue:

```js
var w = 400,
  h = 200;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var rectangle = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 100)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("stroke", "teal");

var circles = svg.selectAll("schrodinger")
  .data(d3.range(100))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return Math.random() * w
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return Math.random() * h
  })
  .attr("r", 4);

circles.each(function() {
  var circle = d3.select(this);
  circle.attr("fill", function() {
    return containing(rectangle, circle) ? "royalblue" : "goldenrod";
  })
});

function containing(container, point) {
  var border = container.node().getBBox();
  var coordinates = {
    left: border.x,
    right: border.x + border.width,
    top: border.y,
    bottom: border.y + border.height
  };
  if (point.attr("cx") > coordinates.left && point.attr("cx") < coordinates.right && point.attr("cy") > coordinates.top && point.attr("cy") < coordinates.bottom) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**Bonus**: using a D3 drag, you can check the position of the circles inside the drag function. Here is a demo, drag the rectangle:

```js
var w = 400,
  h = 200;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var rectangle = svg.append("rect")
  .datum({
    x: 100,
    y: 50
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("stroke", "teal")
  .call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragged));

var circles = svg.selectAll("schrodinger")
  .data(d3.range(100))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return Math.random() * w
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return Math.random() * h
  })
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("pointer-events", "none");

circles.each(function() {
  var circle = d3.select(this);
  circle.attr("fill", function() {
    return containing(rectangle, circle) ? "royalblue" : "goldenrod";
  })
});

function containing(container, point) {
  var border = container.node().getBBox();
  var coordinates = {
    left: border.x,
    right: border.x + border.width,
    top: border.y,
    bottom: border.y + border.height
  };
  if (point.attr("cx") > coordinates.left && point.attr("cx") < coordinates.right && point.attr("cy") > coordinates.top && point.attr("cy") < coordinates.bottom) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
  circles.each(function() {
    var circle = d3.select(this);
    circle.attr("fill", function() {
      return containing(rectangle, circle)  ? "royalblue" : "goldenrod";
    })
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**: In case you want to use `polygonContains`, we first get the rectangle's corners the same way we did in the last snippet, and populate an array named `polygon`. Then, we use it in your selection:

```
circles.each(function() {
    var points = [+d3.select(this).attr("cx"), +d3.select(this).attr("cy")]
    d3.select(this).attr("fill", function() {
        return d3.polygonContains(polygon, points) ? "green" : "red";
    })
});
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var w = 400,
  h = 200;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var rectangle = svg.append("rect")
  .datum({
    x: 100,
    y: 50
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .attr("width", 150)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("stroke", "teal");

var border = rectangle.node().getBBox();
var corners = {
  left: border.x,
  right: border.x + border.width,
  top: border.y,
  bottom: border.y + border.height
};
var polygon = [
  [corners.left, corners.top],
  [corners.right, corners.top],
  [corners.right, corners.bottom],
  [corners.left, corners.bottom]
];

var circles = svg.selectAll("schrodinger")
  .data(d3.range(100))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return Math.random() * w
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return Math.random() * h
  })
  .attr("r", 3);

circles.each(function() {
  var points = [+d3.select(this).attr("cx"), +d3.select(this).attr("cy")]
  d3.select(this).attr("fill", function() {
    return d3.polygonContains(polygon, points) ? "green" : "red";
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's a pretty cool solution. I'm thinking it could work for this specific case. But for the general case, I'd still lean towards something closer to the post title of retrieving the coordinates for `polygonContains`. Maybe the rect to rectangle conversion you were mentioning earlier?

Comment: I can't see the difference, but if it fits you better, then yes, you can convert the rectangle to a polygon and use `polygonContains`.

Comment: Your answer is already very detailed, but maybe for posterity could you add a quick snippet for the rect to polygon? I tried search engine queries and was unable to find anything that retrieves the 4 vertex coordinates. Thank you so much

Comment: I just edited the question. The math for getting the corners is exactly the same one in the previous snippets.

Comment: perfect! I really appreciate the different approaches you demonstrated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
containing_rect.attr("x")
containing_rect.attr("y")
```

to retrive x and y coordinate of the top-left point of the rect and

```
containing_rect.attr("width")
containing_rect.attr("height")
```

to retrieve width and height. Then you'll do the maths ;)